# Upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7.10 to 3.1.1

Tags: java, spring-boot

After I upgraded from  Spring Boot 2.7.10 to 3.1.1, [my project](https://github.com/victorqedu/Appointments) is no longer compiling successffully, the error is:

```
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project appointments: 
    Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    javax.lang.model.element.UnknownElementException: Unknown element: "startOffset" -> [Help 1]
```

The project is just started and is here: https://github.com/victorqedu/Appointments.
As soon as I added the `SpecialitiesController` class, the error appeared.

In Spring Boot 2.7.10, the project compiles successfully (if I switch in `pom.xml` from 3.1.1 to 2.7.10 then the project is compiling with success).

Comment: Spring Boot 3.x requires JDK 17.  The javax.lang.model.element package might not be available in that JDK version.  You should be looking at the release notes to see what changes you need to make to run on JDK 17 and Spring Boot 3.x.

Comment: You should migrate from javax(Java EE) to jakarta (Jakarta EE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments the solution is to migrate from javax(Java EE) to jakarta (Jakarta EE) so I replaced all imports containing "javax" with "jakarta" and now I can compile successfully.